# Replacing content in a file using GIT

Tags: git, github

I'm currently doing a tutorial for Ruby on Rails and they're doing a section on using git. However, they skip over an important step in the process.

I have a Readme file. I want to replace the contents of it with a premade readme message provided by the tutorial. What git command do I use for this? Sorry if this is obvious, but I've spent twenty minutes searching for this; I'm pretty sure I'm not using the right language for what I'm asking.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - can't you just edit the file? I don't see where git comes into it, unless the updated content that you want is in a branch somewhere. If it is, please give more details.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered that, since I was on a one track with git commands. I guess my question then is, is it possible to replace the contents of a text file just using the git command line?

Comment: Again, not unless it's in a repo somewhere. Where would you expect it to get the content from?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I overestimated what it could do. I'll call this one good.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
echo 'foo bar' >Readme
git add Readme
git commit -m 'Update Readme'
```